# How to start to write a Windows context menu

Tags: windows, markdown

I would like to write a context menu for Markdown files for Windows XP, when I right click on a Markdown file it should display "View in browser" option. It could use [MardownSharp](http://code.google.com/p/markdownsharp/) or [Discount](http://www.pell.portland.or.us/~orc/Code/discount/) to convert it in HTML and show it using the default browser. I guess that building such feature shouldn't require too much knowledge of the Windows platform. My question is: where should I start considering the fact that I would want to write this tool without using MS Visual Studio (I would like to use opensource software)? Could it be possible to use [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page)?

Answer (score 1):

See [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4140/markdown-viewer) on how to convert Markdown to HTML.  As far as adding this as a context menu, this is a built-in feature of the Windows registry:

Browse to or create the following key.  This assumes the file extension is `.mdml` (as I am unfamiliar with any set standard on this file format).  If that's not the case, replace `.mdml` with the file extension(s) you are looking for, or `*` for all files, regardless of extension.

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.mdml\Shell\
```

Browse to or create a new sub-key called something like "View in browser" and a sub-sub-key called "Command" (must be this word).  In that key, modify the default to display the program and arguments to launch (e.g. `C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\NOTEPAD.EXE "%1"`).

You should now be able to browse to

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.mdml\Shell\View in browser\Command\
```

and see the launch parameters in `(Default)`.